# tomcat connector change port

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, spring-boot

I´m implementing a simple "Hello World" in Spring Boot. I´m following the tutorial [SpringBoot HelloWorld](http://www.javainuse.com/spring/SpringBoot_HelloWorld)

When I run the class SpringbootHelloworldApplication.java as "Run as Java Aplication" I got the error:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to
>   start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be
>   misconfigured.
>
> Action:
>
> Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process
>   that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen
>   on another port.

I did double click in the server, and it has this configuration:

[image]

I´m not using the port 8080, where should I change the default port?

The server.xml file has:

```
  <Connector port="8085" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: add `server.port=<someotherportnumber>` in application.properties file

Comment: @pvpkiran What is the path to find that file, please

Comment: read the link u had provided there again. It should be under resources

Comment: I added server.port= 8086 . Again I got an error The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8086 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your application looks something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring Boot runs an embedded Tomcat server. When you run SpringbootHelloworldApplication.java class, it actually starts it's own server. You don't need the Eclipse Tomcat connector at all.

It's possible that you have already launched another instance of your application.

Try setting `server.port=0`. This will cause Spring Boot to use a random free port every time it starts.

Comment: Yes, that is the application class. It worked, I didn´t get any error. The question now is, with which port should I test it? I tried with http://localhost:8080/welcome.html . and it displayed "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect". In the console from eclipse, it says "Tomcat started on port(s): 53620 (http)" but it didn´t work "Whitelabel Error Page"

Comment: The port that returned the whitelabel error was correct. That's a separate issue now that's causing that.

Comment: then, with which port should I try, since with 8080 doesn´t work

Comment: Any free port above 1024 is fine. How to find free ports is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

yes , you should try with changing it, sometimes http port may have already taken by other applications. change something like `8006 - tomcat port , HTTP - 8086 , AJP - 8010` and do not forgot to navigate with your new http port.

Comment: at the moment, I just run the java class, the project is not added in the Tomcat server. I tried changing the values, but still, I got the same error

Comment: if you are not adding the project into tomcat server , server is not running your project. And if you want to open management web interface of tomcat, then try to change the role in server.xml of server and open it.

Comment: I followed the tutorial, and they didn´t mention that step. However, I tried to add the project in the Tomcat "Add and Remove" option but the project is not displayed in the list, so I can´t add it. What is missing then?

Comment: what is the error you are getting , something like can't add your project on the top? Or any , And also i did wrongly menton server.xml , it is tomcat-users.xml

Comment: I got a bunch of information about the error, i will summarize, hope it helps

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1031) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]

Comment: does this error helps? I still got other errors before that

Comment: have you changed all the port?, Ya i am looking on it. Try rebut the system. Is there a another instance of tomcat server running?

Comment: now I don´t get any error, but which port should I run it? with 8080 I got "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: What is your http port? is it 8086 or something,  if it's then  you should run on 8086.

Comment: I´m trying the example within a company and I configured in eclipse the http and https proxy port. I wrote a Host name and as port 80. Do I need to try it in a different way? http://localhost:80/welcome.html, like this for example. Or there isn´t any relation between the proxy configurations and the example I want to try

Answer (score 0):

you can do one of two things

1. Add server.port=0 in application.properties file which will randomize your port everytime you run the application but again I wonder why would one want to do that :p
2. You last application instance wasnt properly stopped and is keeping the port busy.To solve that, on the right top side of the console you will see a red button, click this to stop the application properly and your problem is solved. Note: closing the console doesnt free the port the application was running on. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

I think, other applications are take your 8080 port number simple way change your port number in your application.properties file.

```
server.port = 0
```